# Could we take this bijective function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we want to show that the sets:

$$A=\{ 3X^2\mid X \in \mathbb{Z}_p \}\ \  \text{ and } \ \ B=\{ 7-5Y^2\mid Y \in \mathbb{Z}_p\}$$

have the same cardinality, could we take the bijective function $f$ such that $f(x)=\frac{7-5x}{3}$ ? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, can you prove that it is a bijection? If you can, then it is correct.

Comment: What is $\Bbb Z_p$ here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The integer p-adic numbers.

Comment: Do you mean $A=\{3X^2|0\le X<p\}$ or do you mean that $3X^2$ is a p-adic expression?